# How to Add To Cart button instead of Paypal button

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart

I have my own service website, it has many posts (say some 50) and in each post I have kept paypal buttons in order to make payment by my visitors.

But I am thinking to have a shopping cart in place of those paypal buttons so that visitors will give away their email id and also they make payment.

I tried to use wp-ecommerce, BUT unfortunately its forcing me to use URLs something like www.somedomain.com/shop/someservice (or) www.somedomain.com/products-page/someservice

Since I already have many posts and these were indexed too, so I cannot change my URLs too.

So, I need like this: just replacing with some 'Add To Cart' button in place of my paypal button for all of my posts. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You mean just replace the paypal button with 'Add to cart' button? And it would process just the same as you click the paypal button?

Comment: I think this question is abandoned, and can be closed as 'unclear'.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom button that says 'Add to Cart' and in the href="insert paypals api link"